# DAA operation in 8085 microprocessor

Tags: microprocessor, 8085, instruction-set

Let the content of register A is **98H**. Both Auxiliary Carry flag and Carry flag are set i.e. **AC=1** & **Cy=1**. If now I **execute DAA once**, both nibbles will get added with (0110) and the result is FEH having AC=0 & Cy=0. **Is FEH the final result stored in A or will it again add (0110) to convert result into a valid BCD?**

Although I have never found any question like this, just a random doubt about DAA operation.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot arrive at that condition from an addition of two valid BCD numbers. The largest possible LS nibbles are 9, so that means the largest possible LS result with a nibble carry is 2. So it's a moot point.

By the [manual](http://www.nj7p.info/Manuals/PDFs/Intel/205775-002.pdf) description it *should* leave a non-BCD result in the accumulator. An example of [GIGO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out). A consequence of using the (very efficient) "add 6" algorithm on invalid data.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the final answer stored in the Accumulator will be FEH, since you've only given one command of DAA.The sequence would be:-

Add 06 to 98 H (since AC is set) = 9 E H

9 E + 6 0 = F E

So the final answer is FEH.
Check out for [yourself](https://www.sim8085.com/)